# Installing Ricoh SP112 printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, ricoh

A friend lent me an elderly Ricoh SP112 to get me out of a fix when my own printer failed. It self installs on Ubuntu and shows up on the available printers. I can print a test page from the buttons on the printer, but I can't print from the computer. When a job is sent to print, the printer light registers and continues to blink, without printing.
When I check the print queue no job is registered.
I have found some threads on various forums with the same problem, but they are all very old and for older versions of Ubuntu and the links no longer work.

Comment: @user535733 The OP wrote they *can print a test page from the buttons on the printer* which is completely irrelevant except to maybe attest the printer is in good working condition.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, mea culpa. You are, of course, correct.

Comment: It's not at all irrelevant. Making sure the printer was working was exactly the point. You need to make sure the printer is in working order, otherwise there's no point in trying to install it!

Answer (score 1):

There's a PPA providing additional drivers for many Ricoh printers including the SP112 model.

**Important note: The PPA in the following instructions is to be used ONLY in Ubuntu 16.04 (EoL, unsupported), 18.04 and 20.04.** Following the pattern is reasonable to expect it will also support the upcoming LTS, 22.04, but only time will tell.

Update: Also supported for Ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lafricain79/lafricainenvrac
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ricoh-sp-series
```

Original source: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/installer_imprimante_ricoh

Comment: No change. Is there a way to manually install the printer? Where are the downloaded PPD files?

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/vaginessa/ricoh-sp112-ppd

Comment: Whlie the `apt` approach didn't really lead anywhere, the linked page has a working solution using github clone.

Answer (score 0):

For 23.10 and SP112, I essentially followed the same logic as @ChanganAuto's link or the GH repo suggested by @MayeulC.

However, for me only this somewhat more updated version of the repository with the PPDs worked: https://github.com/revisitor/ricoh-sp100/tree/master.

I encountered following issues:

- If I let the system install the default -> printer is detected, jobs can be submitted but it takes forever to process them.
- If I install via ppa -> printer is detected but the submitted job is not received by the printer.
- If I install the old version with same manual steps -> jobs are printed as blank pages.